# Can a Polymer 2.0 PWA be served over HTTPS?

Tags: http, npm, https, polymer, polymer-2.x

I am trying to build my first progressive web app, using the Polymer CLI. I am trying to make my app to load an NPM package, but the console was showing an error when loading it. I think I resolved this issue by moving the dependency into a different directory, as I no longer receive that error in the console. However, my package still isn't executing it's intended purpose. I think this is because `polymer serve` serves on HTTP by default, while my package seems to require HTTPS. I looked at these articles on the polymer website (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-installable-web-apps-with-webapp-manifest-in-chrome-38-for-Android , https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/toolbox/), but they don't seem to refer to HTTPS at all. Am I on a wild goose chase, trying to serve over HTTPS?

Comment: For sure, polymer 2.x could be served over https. Google servers encouragement to use https. like firebase hostings.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, Polymer apps can run over HTTPS. The documentation just needs to be updated. You might find something useful in the [`polyserve` README](https://github.com/Polymer/polyserve/blob/master/README.md) or in running `polymer --help`.

As of version 0.4.0, you can use the `-P` flag of `polymer-cli` to enable HTTPS:

```
polymer serve -P https
```

or enable HTTP2 (uses HTTPS, requires Node 5 or newer) with:

```
polymer serve -P h2
```